# How many RAW dependencies are present in these instructions?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines

What is the number of RAW dependencies in below set of instructions?

```
I1: R1 = R2 - R3
I2: R2 = R1 + R3
I3: R3 = R1 + R2
I4: R1 = R2 - R2
```

I can see the following RAW dependencies in it:

> $I_2-I_1\ for\ R_1$ ......... (a)
>
> $I_3-I_1\ for\ R_1$ ......... (b)
>
> $I_3-I_2\ for\ R_2$ ......... (c)
>
> $I_4-I_2\ for\ R_2$ ......... (d)

I think taking (a) and (b) implies that (c) has already been included. So, should this be counted as 4 RAW dependencies or 3 RAW dependencies?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Read_after_write_(RAW)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: According to a 5-stage pipeline scenario, there are just two true RAW hazards:

```
1. I2 to I1 for R1 
2. I3 to I2 for R2
```

---

Explanation

The answer might depend on the pipeline stages. For the sake of this question, let's consider a basic 5-stage pipeline: Instruction Fetch (IF), Decode (DE), Execute (EX), Memory Op (MEM) and Writeback (WB).

```
    Instr\Cycle      C1   C2   C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8   
 ------------------ ---- ---- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- 
  I1: R1 = R2 - R3   IF   DE   EX1   MEM   WB1                    
  I2: R2 = R1 + R3        IF   DE    EX2   MEM   WB2              
  I3: R3 = R1 + R2             IF    DE    EX3   MEM   WB3        
  I4: R1 = R2 - R2                   IF    DE    EX4   MEM   WB4
```

At first, it may seem like there are many RAW dependencies in this instruction sequence but let's analyze how the pipeline behaves with this sequence. The above table might indicate the following:

1. `EX2` depends on `WB1` (`WB1->EX2`)
2. `EX3` depends on `WB1` (`WB1->EX3`)
3. `EX3` depends on `WB2` (`WB2->EX3`)
4. `EX4` depends on `WB2` (`WB2->EX4`)

After the first stall in the pipeline by `EX2`, the scenario changes a bit. `WB1->EX2` (1) was a true dependency. But, `WB1->EX3` (2) is no more a dependency:

```
    Instr\Cycle      C1   C2   C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8    C9    C10  
 ------------------ ---- ---- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- 
  I1: R1 = R2 - R3   IF   DE   EX1   MEM   WB1                                
  I2: R2 = R1 + R3        IF   DE    EX2   EX2   EX2   MEM   WB2              
  I3: R3 = R1 + R2             IF    DE    DE    DE    EX3   MEM   WB3        
  I4: R1 = R2 - R2                   IF    IF    IF    DE    EX4   MEM   WB4
```

After the second stall in the pipeline by `EX3` (3) (which truly waits for `WB2`), the scenario changes again. Clearly, `WB2->EX4` (4) is revealed to be no more a dependency.

```
    Instr\Cycle      C1   C2   C3    C4    C5    C6    C7    C8    C9    C10   C11   C12  
 ------------------ ---- ---- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- 
  I1: R1 = R2 - R3   IF   DE   EX1   MEM   WB1                                            
  I2: R2 = R1 + R3        IF   DE    EX2   EX2   EX2   MEM   WB2                          
  I3: R3 = R1 + R2             IF    DE    DE    DE    EX3   EX3   EX3   MEM   WB3        
  I4: R1 = R2 - R2                   IF    IF    IF    DE    DE    DE    EX4   MEM   WB4
```

Therefore from our original list above, only following true RAW hazards are revealed:

1. `EX2` depends on `WB1` (`WB1->EX2`)
2. `EX3` depends on `WB2` (`WB2->EX3`)